# Django download a BinaryField as a CSV file

Tags: python, django, csv, admin

I am working with a legacy project and we need to implement a Django Admin that helps download a csv report that was stored as a BinaryField.

The model is something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    csv_report = models.BinaryField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Everything seems to being stored as expected but I have no clue how to decode the field back to a csv file for later use.

I am using something like these (as an admin action on MyModelAdmin class)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
...
actions = ["download_file",]

def download_file(self, request,queryset):
        # just getting one for testing
        contents = queryset[0].csv_report
        encoded_data = base64.b64encode(contents).decode() 
        with open("report.csv", "wb") as binary_file:
            # Write bytes to file
            decoded_image_data = base64.decodebytes(encoded_data)
            binary_file.write(decoded_image_data)    

      response = HttpResponse(encoded_data)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.csv'
        return response
  
    download_file.short_description = "file"
```

But all I download is a scrambled csv file. I don't seem to understand if it is a problem of the format I am using to decode (.decode('utf-8') does nothing either )

PD:
I know it is a bad practice to use BinaryField for this. But requirements are requirements. Nothing to do about it.

EDIT:
As @TimRoberts pointed out, encoding and then decoding is REALLY silly :$. I've changed the method like so:

```
    def download_file(self, request,queryset):

    # print(self,request)
    contents = queryset[0].csv_report

    # print(type(contents))
    encoded_data = base64.b64decode(contents)
    
    with open("my_file.csv", "wb") as binary_file:
        binary_file.write(encoded_data)        

    response = HttpResponse(encoded_data)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=blob.csv'
    return response
  
download_file.short_description = "file"
```

Still I am getting a csv file with something like this:

[image]

Comment: You base64-encode the data then base64-decode it.  That much is silly.  What is scrambled?  Can you post a few lines?

Answer (score 0):

A big fat case of the old RTFM: I was getting carried away by the all base64.. Obviously I didn't have any idea of what I was doing.
After tampering with the shell and reading the docs, I just changed my method to:

```
def download_file(self, request,queryset):
 **contents = bytes(queryset[0].csv_report)**
 response = HttpResponse(contents)
 response['ContentDisposition']='attachment;filename=report.csv'
 return response
```

Note that I was scrambling the data on purpose by doing the  **encoded_data = base64.b64decode(contents)** stuff. I just needed to apply bytes on my BinaryField and voilá